# "Error: failure in catalog resolve" thrown after setting Sitecore Commerce in localhost

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, commerce-server

I've set up Sitecore XP 8.2 update 7 via SIM and I am following steps in

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html#Concepts/c_SC_SetUpCommerceServerSite.html 
To setup Sitecore Commerce.

After setting Sitecore Commerce Server, when I try to run `Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Powered.by.SitecoreCommerce.10.0.xxx.update` package again, I get an error while accessing the site as follows:

```
 "Error: failure in catalog resolve, hr: -2147483326"
```

Sitecore logs don't show any details. However, Windows event logs show following errors:

1. Error: failure in catalog resolve, hr: -2147483326
2. Catalog Load failed catalog: Profile Definitions (-2147483326)
3. DataSource::Init(DS-1-Profile Definitions) failed on catalog load
   (-904429548)
4. In BindArgs::OpenDataSrc(), failed initializing data source
   (-904429548)

Can someone suggest any resolutions for this error?

Comment: Which version of Commerce are you installing? 8.2.1 Update 2?

Comment: 8.2.1 update 3. I realized that the tables in profiles database were not all there. Managed to fix the issue by following http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS82/SitecoreCommerceDeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html#ImportProfileSchemaCatalogManager.html